# Date range queries mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, mongodb-query

I've two collections one is `random` and other one is 'msg'

In message I've a document like

```
{ "message": "sssss", postedAt: Fri Jul 17 2015 09:03:43 GMT+0530 (IST) }
```

For random collection, there is a script which generates random number every minute

like

```
 { "randomStr": "sss", postedAt: Fri Jul 17 2015 09:03:43 GMT+0530 (IST) }
 { "randomStr": "xxx", postedAt: Fri Jul 17 2015 09:04:43 GMT+0530 (IST) }
 { "randomStr": "yyy", postedAt: Fri Jul 17 2015 09:05:43 GMT+0530 (IST) }
```

Notice the change in timings, for every mintute there is a new record.

Now, my issue is

when I query for `message` collection, I'll get one record.

Lets's say this

```
{ "message": "sssss", postedAt: Fri Jul 17 2015 09:03:13 GMT+0530 (IST) }
```

now I want to get the record from `random` collection which posts at exact minute

this message is posted at `09:03`, I want to get the record from `random` collection which postedat exactly same time `09:03`.

How to do that? Any help appreciated. Thx.

**Note:** I'm doing this in meteor

**Edit**

Added image for first comment
[image]

Comment: Is not as simple as this?
`db.random.find({"postedAt" : $date });`

Comment: @gastonmancini, If the seconds are different it is not working, added image as proof in question. Thx for the reply

Answer (score 1):

So the point here is 'actually use a range' and also be aware of the `Date` value you get in return. So as a basic example in principle.

The time right now as I execute this is:

```js
var date = new Date()
ISODate("2015-07-17T04:02:04.471Z")
```

So if you presume then that your actual timestamp in the document is "not exactly to the minute" (like above) nor is it likely the "random record" is so then the first thing to do is "round" it to the minute:

```js
date = new Date(date.valueOf() - date.valueOf() % ( 1000 * 60 ))
ISODate("2015-07-17T04:02:00Z")
```

And of course the "end date" is just one minute after that:

```js
var endDate = new Date(date.valueOf() + ( 1000 * 60 ))
ISODate("2015-07-17T04:03:00Z")
```

Then when you query "rqndom" you just get the "range", with [**`$gte`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/gte/) and [**`$lt`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/lt/) operators:

```js
db.random.find({ "postedAt": { "$gte": date, "$lt": endDate } })
```

Which just retrieves your single "write once a minute" item from "random" at any possible value within that minute.

So basically:

- Round your input retrieved date to the minute
- Search on the "range" betweeen that value and the next minute

Comment: thx for the answer and will try this, I had same thing in mind but thought we might loose date object reference if we change the date values, do we loose that?

Comment: @noName Depends on what you do. You can always cast to a new variable with the "rounded" values from the source within your retrieved document, just as shown. And that is probably the safest thing to to. You can do other methods that manipulate the date value as retrieved, but I have not shown those here.